# LDAP query to get list of members in an AD group

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I checked a few posts asked the similar questions before, but none works for my case, not sure if something wrong on my side or it's the AD.

So I have security group at path:

```
CN=MigratedUsers,OU=Azure Groups,OU=Security Groups,OU=National Organization,DC=abc,DC=firm,AD
```

And in the MigratedUsers group, there is a member property with a few AD users in the group.
I am trying to get the list of users, so I can iterate through them.

So in my base location I specified:

```
OU=Azure Groups,OU=Security Groups,OU=National Organization,DC=abc,DC=firm
```

For the LDAP Filter I have:

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=MigratedUsers,OU=Azure Groups,OU=Security Groups,OU=National Organization,DC=abc,DC=firm))
```

The result returned 0 records.

I tried other combinations such as `(&(objectCategory=group)(CN=MigratedUsers))`, it doesn't work either.

So, could anyone point out to me if anything in my query is wrong or I need to start checking something else like AD settings etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first filter looks fine :

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=MigratedUsers,OU=Azure Groups,OU=Security Groups,OU=National Organization,DC=abc,DC=firm))
```

But the search base is not, (it's a group search base, while you want to retrieve user entries). The user base should look like this :

```
OU=Users,OU=National Organization,DC=abc,DC=firm
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's the issue and also in the root, I accidently included the word AD in the path "DC=abc,DC=firm,AD"

Answer (score 1):

You're searching for users, but you set the base of the search to:

```
OU=Azure Groups,OU=Security Groups,OU=National Organization,DC=abc,DC=firm
```

That tells it to only return users that are in the `Azure Groups` OU. I'm guessing that there are no users in that OU. Set the base of the search to the root of the domain (e.g. `DC=abc,DC=firm`), or just don't set it at all, since that will be the default.

Your first filter is the correct one (which has the full DN of the group).